# How to force addJs in Magento to run async

Tags: javascript, magento, magento-1.7

I am wondering if there is an easy way, a param? perhaps, for the standard Magento addJs:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
```

to make it something like:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script><param>async</param></action>
```

The reason for my inquiry is I am attempting to load all of my js files asynchronously. They are being called by the page.xml file of my theme. A quick change like this would be easy to make.

My current output is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.com/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
```

I would like to output this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.com/js/prototype/prototype.js" async></script>
```

or this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.com/js/prototype/prototype.js" async="async"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

i have had some issues with async because some of my javascript needs to be loaded as soon as the page load, i tried this `<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.filterexpandcollapse.js</name><params>async</params></action>` in local.xml and it works.

We can change too the head.php in Mage/Page/Block/HTML folder if all the scripts can run in async mode.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

If you just tried it you'd already know that it works. Your code works.

Look at `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` and you'll see the methods and their parameters.

Comment: I did try it and still get no async="async" in my <script> tag

Comment: Which version are you using? None of the above versions made any difference in the output code for me.